# Мусорить, замусорить, намусорить: какие глаголы переходные, а какие нет?

Tags: грамматика, глаголы, переходные, непереходные

Заданы три глагола: ***мусорить, замусорить, намусорить.***

Какие их них **переходные**, а какие нет? Как это определить **по словарю**?